# What could be the cause for the MediaPipe installation error on Windows with Python 3.8.3?

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

I try to install *MediaPipe* on Windows, but it doesn't work. What can I do now?

The command line used to start the installation with my user´s profile directory being the current directory:

```
pip install mediatype
```

The output error messages are:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
> WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: There is on homepage of [MediaPipe](https://mediapipe.dev/) at top in the menu a link to the [Docs](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/). The chapter [Getting Started](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/getting_started.html) contains a link to the page [Troubleshooting](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/troubleshooting.html) with the chapter [Python pip install failure](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/troubleshooting.html#python-pip-install-failure) which is exactly about this error message and how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mediapipe doesn't support 32-bit python; all of the [wheels](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files) are for 64-bit python.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above you say...
pip install mediatype

If you are truly trying to install mediapipe then you have a typo.

It should be...
pip install mediapipe

Answer (score -1):

mediapipe does not support 32-bit python. Go ahead, upgrade to 64-bit python and enjoy!